# How do I fix the jaggedness and darkness around the edges of 2D textures in WebGL?

Tags: glsl, webgl, antialiasing, alphablending

I've tried setting the `antialias` property on the WebGL context to true, but that didn't fix it.

This is what I'm getting in WebGL:

[image: WebGL (what I'm getting)]

This is canvas rendering, via `drawImage`, which is what I'm trying to replicate:

[image: Canvas (what I want)]

I'm using the default WebGL settings, aside from these three changed flags:

```js
gl.enable(gl.BLEND); // Enable blending
gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL); //near things obscure far things
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

And here's how I load the sprites (with the `sprite` variable being an Image object)

```js
const texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, sprite);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
```

Comment: That's aliasing. Without more information, like how your sampler is configured, resolutions involved, etc., this is difficult to answer.

Comment: @3Dave I've added more information, does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, fixed it. It was happening because my textures used premultiplied alpha values, which messed up the blending.

I fixed it by changing my `blendFunc` from `gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` to `gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`

I also had to tell WebGL to unpack premultiplied alpha values by doing
`gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_PREMULTIPLY_ALPHA_WEBGL, true)`